# My old flutter code is not working ,the build method fails

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies

[Error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzkhc.png)
my old flutter code is not working after i came back to it to integrate it with an api can someone help me with this

i tried to use flutter pub upgrade i did clean and get but still nothing worked

so please help me if you know whats wrong

Comment: Your error is already saying what are the issues in your app. It's not related any building process. It's mostly related the things have changed from your app's flutter version and current flutter version. For Example: I'm able to see that the `TapDownDetails` is changed with `TapDownDragDetails` for GestureDetector method.

Answer (score 0):

Since you run flutter pub upgrade, you now need to update your code accordingly, according to the error you have highlighted, you just need to change the type of function to what it is asking for. Instead of using tapupdetails or tapdowndetails, use tapDragupdetails and tapdragdowndetails, please confirm the letter casing from the libraries documentation or the error message. Also, if you had uploaded a screenshot or code sample of your code, it would have been much more beneficial

Comment: but im not using tapdowndetails or tapupdetails  and i dont know which file the error is coming from